# toLocaleDateString - A good way to get a date format string?

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to get a date format string in the user's preferred format by creating a static date, parsing it to a string with [`Date.toLocateDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) and then converting the values in the string to those required by a date formatting string.

The code looks like this:

```js
const compose = (...fns) =>
  fns.reduceRight((prevFn, nextFn) =>
    (...args) => nextFn(prevFn(...args)),
    value => value
  );
  
const stringReplace = (s1, s2) => (s3) => s3.replace(s1, s2);

const getDateFormatString = ({
    days,
    months,
    years,
}) => {
     const convertToDateFormatString = compose(
        stringReplace('2021', years),
        stringReplace("12", months),
        stringReplace('31', days),
     );

     return convertToDateFormatString(
        new Date(2021, 11 ,31).toLocaleDateString()
     );
};

console.log(getDateFormatString({ days: 'dd', years: 'yyyy', months: 'MM' }))
```

My problem is that, however I change my browser's locale (I've tried via extensions and directly via. settings) I still seem to get the same format. I had expected it to pick up the locale from the browser, as MDN states in an example:

```js
console.log(event.toLocaleDateString(undefined, options));
// expected output: Thursday, December 20, 2012 (varies according to default locale)
```

I have checked the language which my browser is using - setting it either to `en` or `en-gb` - but both give the save result for the expression:

```js
new Date().toLocaleDateString()
```

However, I get the correct answer when I use:

```js
new Date().toLocaleDateString(navigator.languages[0])
```

I'm guessing there's a piece missing in my understanding of how my browser (Chrome) is determining the locale to use in this function. Could anyone offer any guidance?

Comment: You can check the current locale in the console by typing `navigator.languages`

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks - that's useful - I've updated my answer

Comment: Passing in an empty array may work, if it's anything like [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat)'s constructor, but honestly, getting a date format string from `toLocaleDateString` is not the right way around. I'd use `DateTimeFormat`'s `formatToParts`; then you'd get the literal used as separators as well. You might take inspiration from my work here: https://github.com/mikemccaughan/heretic-monkey.link/blob/master/hm-datetimepicker/DateFormatter.mjs#L413

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks, I'll take a look!